# Extract binaries from pcap using command line (script)

Tags: linux, bash, networking, scripting

I'm looking for a way to extract binaries from PCAP's using the command line. I realize it is possible using Wireshark -> File -> Export -> http objects etc. But `tshark` doesn't seem to support this.

Is there a way to do this or code around this, preferably using `python` or `bash`. Or does anyone know of tools that can do this that I am not aware of.

I'd prefer if the method is automatable / scriptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [tcpextract](http://pypi.python.org/Pypi/tcpextract/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I will look in to it. Not accepting yet, going to see if other people suggest other tools. +1

Answer (score 1):

As of Wireshark 2.3.0, you can export HTTP objects with tshark. (Wireshark 2.3.0 hasn't been released yet, so you can grab a daily build from [here](https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/win32/).)

To extract HTTP objects from the command-line, run the following command:

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap --export-objects "http,destdir"
```